# Изменение стиля когда заканчивается размер в блоке

Tags: css3

Есть блок меню, в нем содержится неизвестное к-во пунктов меню(меняется динамически). 
Хотелось бы, что бы когда экран сжимается на ширину, менее чем занимают все пункты меню, меню переходило в режим для мобильных устройств.
В статическом меню все просто,

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px)
```

решает проблему, но хотелось бы, вместо

```
(max-width: 600px)
```

задать условие - "блоку с меню больше некуда сжиматься".

Такое вообще возможно? Или медиа запросы это путь не в том направлении?

Comment: Возможно на js.